# Patrick's Bed Sheets

Tags: plot-explanation, american-psycho

Toward the beginning of [American Psycho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Psycho_%28film%29) Patrick is at the dry cleaners yelling at the workers because his bed sheets are still stained with "cranapple juice."

I've come to the conclusion that the murders were all in his head and that he had some sort of multiple personality disorder because Paul Allen called him Marcus and his lawyer did also

When he was dragging Paul Allen's body through the lobby of his apartment complex nobody said anything, there were traces of blood everywhere and the man asked him where he got the bag (if the murders weren't in his head it would just be symbolic of how upper class people are oblivious to things outside of themselves).

What about the bed sheets?

That's the only thing that is making me think that maybe he did kill people, because his old friend saw the sheets and seemed to be very curious about the red stains on them.

Comment: I've added some paragraphs to make this more readable - I think it could benefit from you adding a final sentence to sum up what your question is... For example "Was it all in his head?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that was the beauty of the movie, we really did not know if he was insane committing these crimes or insane imagining himself committing these crimes. Or if all, some or none of these events actually took place. Maybe he is in a nut ward imagining all this?!

The movie started as a first person narrative  and can be assumed to have continued as such. If he was insane an narrating it we can never really know what happened.  Who he really is (Patrick or Marcus),  did he kill the prostitutes? Will he or is he just imagining?

Thank you for bringing this movie up,  it makes you think about where the baseline of sanity/reality is in the movie to reference from.  It really can't be determined in my opinion. So anything in the story can be real or not yet all codependent one one another. Mind blown! Love this movie!